# AWS Firehose to Elastic Search - Transforming one Firehose record into multiple Elastic entries

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have an optimized (normalized) JSON string incoming to my Lambda function. It gets forwarded to Firehose to Elastic Search.
My plan is to use a Kinesis Data Transformation Lambda (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html) to denormalize the JSON to get proper Elastic Search entries out of it.
This question ist about doability/how to do it.

This is my basic AWS setup:

1. Lambda function: takes a normalized JSON from internet, validates it, appends some properties, forwards it to Kinesis Firehose via `putRecord`.
2. Kinesis Firehose transformation lambda: gets the one record, reads the JSON and generates multiple items out of it, returns it back to Firehose which forwards it to Elastic Search

My question is: Is it possible that Firehose/the transformation lambda can create multiple Elastic Search entries out of one record?
I'll try to visualize the scenario with some pseudo code:

**lambda.js**

```js
exports.handler = async function (event) {
    // 1. get inputDoc from request, which contains multiple es_documents
    // 2. attach timestamp as property
    // result:
    const inputDoc = {
        request_logged_at: '2017-02-07T15:13:01.39256Z',
        es_documents: [
            {
                foo: 'bar'
            },
            {
                foo: 'baz'
            }
        ]
    };

    const firehoseParams = {
        DeliveryStreamName: 'Delivery-Stream',
        Record: {
            Data: JSON.stringify(inputDoc)
        }
    };

    await firehose.putRecord(firehoseParams).promise();
    return { statusCode: 201 };
}
```

firehose/transform_lambda.js

```js
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    const record = event.records[0];
    const myDoc = (new Buffer(record.data, 'base64')).toString('utf8');

    // Denormalize request_logged_at into the single documents, so every document in Elastic knows when it got logged
    const docsToElastic = myDoc.es_documents.map(doc => {
        return doc.request_logged_at = myDoc.request_logged_at;
    });

    // This is the main point: How to return this array back to Firehose so Elastic creates multiple table entries?
    // My first guess is the following, as I've seen this syntax in other places 
    // (see first "Note" on this page[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/record-format-conversion.html])
    const result = docsToElastic.reduce((accumulator, doc) => {
        return accumulator + JSON.stringify(doc);
    }, '');

    // result: '{"foo":"bar","request_logged_at":"2017-02-07T15:13:01.39256Z"}{"foo":"baz","request_logged_at":"2017-02-07T15:13:01.39256Z"}'

    const payload = (new Buffer(result, 'utf8')).toString('base64');
    return {
        recordId: record.recordId,
        result: 'Ok',
        data: payload
    };
}
```

Can anyone share his knowledge about this use-case? Will this work?

BTW: I know I could do the denormalization in the first lambda and use `firehose.putRecordBatch()`, but the first lambda has already a lot of tasks and it's also a matter of separating concerns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it myself. These hints from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-deliver.html) gave me an idea:

> It [Firehose] then generates an Elasticsearch bulk request to index multiple records to your Elasticsearch cluster. Make sure that your record is UTF-8 encoded and flattened to a single-line JSON object before you send it to Kinesis Data Firehose.

So what actually happens under the hood is that Firehose performs an [ES bulk request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html). So what Firehose probably does:

```js
    POST _bulk
    { "index" : { "_index" : "my-index" } }
    [FirehoseRecord.Data]
    { "index" : { "_index" : "my-index" } }
    [FirehoseRecord.Data]
    { "index" : { "_index" : "my-index" } }
    [FirehoseRecord.Data]
```

So what I did was to modify **one** `FirehoseRecord.Data` to have multiple lines of my documents, separated each by the `{ "index" : ...}` object:

```js
const result = docsToElastic.reduce((accumulator, log, currentIndex) => {
    return accumulator +
        // Skip index at first time bcs. that is what Firehose does
        (currentIndex === 0 ? '' : '{ "index" : { "_index" : "my-index"} }' + '\n') +
        JSON.stringify(log) + '\n';
}, '');
```

Output:

```js
{"foo":"bar","request_logged_at":"2017-02-07T15:13:01.39256Z"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my-index" } }
{"foo":"bar","request_logged_at":"2017-02-07T15:13:01.39256Z"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my-index" } }
{"foo":"bar","request_logged_at":"2017-02-07T15:13:01.39256Z"}
```

Pay attention to the first misisng `{ "index" : ...}` object. This is because Firehose adds the first `{ "index" : ...}` itself before the whole Record.

This is tested and working right now.